# ASP.NET: Saving and displaying value passed from URL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have passed a string value `farmName` from one controller to another.

```
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="JFTreatment" asp-route-farmName="@item.Farm.Name">link</a>
```

I can see in my index view that it has been passed successfully:

[image: MY URL]

I would now like to display the `farmName` as a title in my edit view, but I am unsure of the syntax of how to set a session string or how to display it.

Comment: Will you include your Index controller action that receives the url parameters? Thanks

Comment: As of now there is no controller action that receives the url parameters. I just know that it as has been passed because I see it in the url along with the plotId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
I did it using session string

I received the URL through

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index( string farmName){
HttpContext.Session.SetString("farmName", farmName);}
```

Then just set add the reference

`@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`

Then set the title with

`ViewData["Title"] = @Context.Session.GetString("farmName");`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're setting your Title using `ViewData["Title"]` dictionary that is set on every page. You can do the following to get the `farmName` from Url.

**Option 1: Get the query value directly from Query Collection**

```
foreach(var query in HttpContext.Request.Query)
{
  if(query.Key == "farmName")
  {
    ViewData["Title"] = query.Value;
  }
}
```

**Option 2: Get your route data as method parameter (Recommended)**

For this option to work, your `Index` method should look like this:

```
public IActionResult Index(string farmName, int? plotId = null){
  ViewData["Title"] = farmName;
  ... Some more code
}
```

Here the route property is received via Action Parameter...